# Can I prevent ejs from evaluating a date with a hyphen in it?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am creating an array with a for loop for a series of dates that are in this format '2019-04'. The problem is that ejs is evaluating this as a subtraction and giving me '2015'.

```
var labels = []
<%for(var i = 0; i < totals.length; i++) { %>
    labels.push(<%= totals[i].period%>+",")
    console.log(labels)
<%}%>
```

The expected result should always be the date in the format YYYY-MM but the results are a subtraction so for 2018-12 I get 2006, 2019-1 I get 2018 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I only needed to include the ejs tags in quotations and didn't need them on the comma

```
        labels.push("<%= totals[i].period %>",)
```